# Display graphic spinner if a bash script is running

Tags: python, bash

**I have some scripts in bash and I need to display graphic spinner if the script is running. (some scripts uses wget)**

**Example**

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/wine-1.7.19.tar.bz2
```

**I can capture this wget with my simple script notify-send...**

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVICE='wget'
SERVICE2='curl'
SERVICE3='myscript'

while [[ $(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c $SERVICE3) -gt 0 ]]
do
if [[ $(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c $SERVICE3) -gt 0 ]] && [[ $(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c $SERVICE) -gt 0 ]] || [[ $(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c $SERVICE2) -gt 0 ]] ; then 

notify-send "Downloading wine 
Please wait" -i "/usr/share/icons/acciones/loadingimage.png" 
exit
fi

done
```

**I found the next example written in python, but I haven't knowledge to integrate it, to my bash scripts.**

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk
import sys


class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    # a window

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Spinner Example", application=app)
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.set_border_width(30)

        # a spinner
        self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
        # that by default spins
        self.spinner.start()
        # add the spinner to the window
        self.add(self.spinner)

    # event handler
    # a signal from the keyboard (space) controls if the spinner stops/starts
    def do_key_press_event(self, event):
        # keyname is the symbolic name of the key value given by the event
        keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
        # if it is "space"
        if keyname == "space":
            # and the spinner is active
            if self.spinner.get_property("active"):
                # stop the spinner
                self.spinner.stop()
            # if the spinner is not active
            else:
                # start it again
                self.spinner.start()
        # stop the signal emission
        return True


class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Comment: Have you tried starting your spinner as another thread before running your script and killing it when it ends? Just make an executable file that just show the spinner and that locks itself from being closed easily by the user and you should be good to go.

Comment: If your bash script runs in a terminal then why not use a text-based spinner? Otherwise you will have two windows (bash/spinner) and it will be disjointed. Alternatively implement your download code in Python.

Comment: @MomemtumMori I have not tried, but I like this spinner will automatically close when finished some wget process.

Comment: @invert runs silently in a graphical interface, so I need the user to see that the script is working.